# Can we live forever by taking advantage of the time dilation effect?

Tags: time, reference-frames, relativity, twin-paradox

I have been reading about Time dilation and twin paradox in Relativity. So,I thought that if It can be the difference of 10 yrs between the Girl in space and on Earth, then why can't anyone not age rather. Is it possible?

[I'm 14 and new in the field of modern physics, so pls correct if I'm wrong. I regard All of You as teachers.]

Comment: No, you can't. Suppose you are prescribed by a doctor, you should walk 1 hour in the rocket. Then your twin and you both should have walk 1 hour (respective to their own clock)  a day to keep you fit. But if your twin looks at you through a telescope then he will find that you walked only 45 minutes (suppose). But you walked 1 hour according to your clock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

General relativity is not going to help you 'live forever'. Sure, you might develop the technology to hover a tiny distance above the horizon of a black hole. Your aging will slow down. People on earth will observe you outlive your parent by many millions of years. By any number of years really.

However, this doesn't help you live 'forever'. All physical processes in your body would slow down. Your hearth beat, the speed at which your neurons fire, your speed of thought: all of it will slow down. Key is that your 'sum total of experiences' would not grow according to the time dilation effects you plan to exploit.

Comment: his body will slow down with respect to the observer at earth.

Comment: So in summary, you can use time dilation to travel to a future an arbitrarily long time after you would have died without it. But it won't "buy you time": you'll still age at one second per second in your frame of reference and this is the same as in your perception.